# How can I directly org-attach from M-x locate results?

Tags: org-mode, dired, org-attach, locate

What I'm trying to do is use `org-attach-dired-to-subtree` when I find something I'm looking for with `M-x locate`.

That doesn't work, cause `M-x locate` results is not a dired buffer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`C-h m` in the `*Locate*` buffer says:

```
V visits the directory of the file on the current line.
This function runs ‘locate-mode-hook’ before returning.
```

<s>so you could (possibly - I have not tried it) even do the `org-attach-dired-to-subtree` from the hook.</s> No, this is nonsense: I misinterpeted `this function` in the last sentence: it does not refer to `locate-find-directory` (which is bound to `V`), it refers to `locate-mode` itself.

EDIT: Here's a simple function that wraps the relevant pieces to org-attach a single file from the `*Locate*` buffer:

```el
(defun my/locate-org-attach-file ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((file (locate-get-filename)))
    (locate-find-directory)
    (org-attach-dired-to-subtree (list file))))
```

Comment: Thanks for this one. It opens the Dired buffer, but it's not jumping to the file, so I have to search for it anew, inside the Dired buffer. Anyways, it does solve the problem, so thanks;)

Comment: See edited answer for  a single-file function. You could probably implement a bulk function by looping over marked files in the `*Locate*` buffer but there are a couple of complications (possilbe non-uniqueness of file names is one).